# ¿Por qué no puedo acceder a este servidor?

Tags: php, html, mysql, docker

estaba realizando con proyecto con Docker y la verdad todo iba bien hasta que al probar lo que había hecho me salto esto en la pantalla.
No comprendo que puede estar pasando así que me gustaría que me ayudaran aquellas personas que tengan cierta experiencia en el tema de Docker y contenedores adjunto la imagen que refleja el problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bueno. Nos podrías incluir en la pregunta qué es lo que intentas hacer, no?

Comment: Porque no tienes permisos

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.